# How do I SELECT data between two dates with the dates as a variable

Tags: python, sqlite

Using Sqlite3 and Python, I want to able to get data between two dates with the dates as a variable.
For example

```
date1 = 2020-10-16
date2 = 2020-10-18

"SELECT SUM (total) FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN '%"+date1+"%' AND '%"+date2+"%'"
```

How can I have BETWEEN grab the date in the variables. When I run this and print the query, the sum is 0 even though I place values inside the rows in (total)

Comment: 2020-10-16=1994 This is probably not what you want to store in date1. Rather make a string out of it.

Comment: @Community the duplicate link that you propose has nothing to do with this question.

Answer (score 2):

Your variables should be strings:

```
date1 = "2020-10-16"
date2 = "2020-10-18"
```

because a variable like:

```
date1 = 2020-10-16
```

is evaluated as `1994` = 2020 - 10 -16.

You should use `?` placeholders in your query for the 2 date parameters:

```
query = "SELECT SUM(total) AS total FROM tablename WHERE date BETWEEN ? AND ?"
```

and pass the parameters when you execute the query:

```
curs.execute(query, (date1, date2))
```